# ASP MVC 4 Websites show up as "Class Library" output type in Visual Studio (2012)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

Is it normal for an ASP MVC 4 "empty template" web site to have an output type in Visual Studio set to "Class Library"? I can still debug/run the site as intended, but there's some internal discussion on our team as to whether or not the output type  as Class Library is intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think so - after all, it's not a standalone .exe, but something loaded and invoked by IIS (or another web server).